# SPList vs SharePointclientObj.List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

What is the difference betweeen these?

I am trying to programatically (on a NON sharepoint server computer) get sharepoint lists (I am an admin of these lists) and convert them into SQL Tables.

So far I have been able to open the lists but not get the datatable. I keep getting code snippets some using SharePointclientObj.List and others using SPList. The SPList isnt found with my assembly references?

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using SharePointclientObj = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

and sadly enough the code that I am finding to do what I want is using the SPList. Can I either get code to convert to a dataTable using the SharePointclientObj.List or an explination on how to get the SPList to connect properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPList object is part of Server Object Model which can be used only on computer where SharePoint resides. To get data remotely you need to use one of SharePoint's remote APIs. `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` which you mentioned is one of them called Client Object Model. You can find some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx).